# В чем отличие 2 режимов (ROUND_UP, ROUND_CEILING) округления Decimal чисел в python?

Tags: python

Объясните в чем отличие 2 режимов (`ROUND_UP`, `ROUND_CEILING`) округления `Decimal` чисел в python.
В документации какие-то странные фразы, которые я не могу расшифровать.

- `ROUND_UP` - "Round away from zero"
- `ROUND_CEILING` - "Round towards Infinity"

А результаты эти 2 режима дают одинаковые. (По крайней мере я не смог найти отличий)

Для примера код

```py
from decimal import *
num = Decimal('3.4555')
print(num.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), ROUND_CEILING))
print(num.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), ROUND_UP))
```

Comment: попробуйте на отрицательных числах

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да теперь понятно. Спасибо. На отрицательных числах я не догадался попробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу на вопрос. Спасибо @AlexeyTen за наводку, что разница очевидна для отрицательных чисел.

Если просто, то модификатор `ROUND_UP` работает как `ROUND_CEILING` на положительных числах, и как `ROUND_FLOOR` на отрицательных.

Фраза из документации "Round away from zero" тогда становится понятной. При округлении `ROUND_UP` мы "движемся" по направлению от 0 на числовой прямой, то есть уменьшаем данное число, если оно отрицательное, и увеличиваем, если положительное.